# Get Multiple download progress update of each download using NSOperationQueue and ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest, nsoperationqueue

iam using to download multiple file using by pass ASIHTTPRequest to operation queue...

```
    NSInvocationOperation *operation =[[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(DownloadFile:) object:url];
.
.
.

-(void)DownloadFile:(NSURL)url{
      ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startSynchronous];
}

- (void)setProgress:(float)progress{    
    NSLog(@"Current progress %f :",progress);

}
```

The progress is working fine but i can't know from which URL or from which operation..
I want to know how to get each download progress of each url individually...
and how i cancel each one not cancel all operations.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First an answer to your question: how about you create one **"delegate" object for each download**? Then it's obvious how download progresses for each download and cancel is easy, too. The code will be more complicated, though.

Therefore I have another suggestion: the [author of ASIHTTPRequest library has stopped developing the library](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;), so you might **switch to something else**. He's suggestion for example [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking), but many people recommend nowadays [MKNetworkKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/). It seems to have pretty good queue handling.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but can you send me more info regarding MKNetworkKit how can i use have you any documentation regarding this solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Note the signature of the delegate messages: Each one takes an argument. That argument is the request sending you the message: The request, when it sends you a delegate message, includes itself among the arguments so that you know which request has gotten that far.

Comment: @MinaNabil: The request sends itself as one of the arguments to each of the delegate messages, so when you receive a message from a request telling you the request's progress, you already know which request you're the message is about.

Comment: but there is no ASIHTTPRequest *request parameter send in Setprogress so i can catch request details...

Comment: @MinaNabil: `setProgress:` is the convenience method of the delegate protocol, for simple cases (so you can just set a UIProgressIndicator as the delegate). Assuming you can't do that, yours is a slightly more complex case, since you have multiple requests, so you need to use the more advanced methods that include a request among the arguments.

Comment: so can you suggest me a solution.. Please i need to figure it out iam in need to this solution !!!

Comment: @MinaNabil: The solution is to implement the other delegate methods, not `setProgress:`.